# I can't retrieve the xcdatamodeld data from the app on the widgetKit extension

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Hello  I can't retrieve the xcdatamodeld data from my app on the widgetKit extension.
Yet I added the appGroup for both.check my models and the xcdatamodeld file for both .

my class coreData :

```
public class CoreDataStackT4U {
    static let shared = CoreDataStackT4U()

    private init() {}

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ios")
        let storeURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.fr.app")!.appendingPathComponent("ios.sqlite")

        var defaultURL: URL?
        if let storeDescription = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first, let url = storeDescription.url {
            defaultURL = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) ? url : nil
        }

        if defaultURL == nil {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)]
        }
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
                       if let error = error as NSError? {
                           print(error.localizedDescription)
                       }
                   })
                   return container
               }()
}

// MARK: - Main context
extension CoreDataStackT4U {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func saveContext() {
        managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and  my class widget:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct t4uWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    var moc = CoreDataStackT4U.shared.managedObjectContext
       @FetchRequest(entity: Vehicle.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
              NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Vehicle.name, ascending: true)
          ]) var vehicles: FetchedResults<Vehicle>

    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                   Spacer()
                   Text("White Tiger")
                    .font(.body)
                       .bold()
                       .padding(.bottom, 20)
                       .padding(.leading, 20)
                       .padding(.trailing, 20)
                       .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                       .foregroundColor(.white)
                       .shadow(
                           color: Color.black,
                           radius: 1.0,
                           x: CGFloat(4),
                           y: CGFloat(4))
                Spacer()
                Text("Items count: \(vehicles.count)")
                                        
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(
                            color: Color.black,
                            radius: 1.0,
                            x: CGFloat(4),
                            y: CGFloat(4))
                
               }
               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
               .background(
                Color.blue.opacity(0.8))
           }
    }


@main
struct t4uWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "t4uWidget"
    let moc = CoreDataStackT4U.shared.managedObjectContext
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            t4uWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
         .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My t4u widget")
        .description("This is t4u widget.")
    }
}

struct t4uWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        t4uWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

the request for vehicles is always 0.
Thank you for your help, giving an example will be useful because I don't see the error.

Comment: `@FetchRequest` cannot be used in Widgets. See [Fetch data from CoreData for iOS 14 widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63936425/8697793)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add :

```
let storeURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.fr.app")!.appendingPathComponent("ios.sqlite")
```

in AppDelegate to my APP thanks.